# How does this code compiles successfully?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int a[1];
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = 2;
    a[2] = 6;
    printf("%d\n", a[2]);
}
```

Although `a` is array of size `1`, why does it accept `a[2] = 6`?

Comment: `a[2]` is just a referrence to the address that is `2*sizeof(int)` away from `a[0]`.... you are just accessing out of bounds

Comment: `c` does not provide array bounds checking.

Answer (score 3):

> *Although a is array of size 1 then does it accepts a[2]=6?*

You *think* it *accepts* because it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Arrays are 0 based indexing in C, and for an array with size 1, only `arr[0]` is valid access, not even `arr[1]`. Attempt to access any other index other than 0 in this case will cause out-of-bound access which invokes UB.

By default C spec does not provide any bound checking for array indexing, so you don;t get an *error* by default. However, if you enable compiler warnings, you should be able to get a hint, at least. FWIW, `-Warray-bounds=1` with `-O2` should warn you.

That said, for a general hosted environment, the signature of `main()` is `int main(void)` in case you don't want to use any command line arguments for the program.